# Merge sort on array of string C

Tags: c++, c, mergesort

Is it possible to merge sort an array of strings? For example if I have an array of strings in C like...

```
arr[0]="Hello";
arr[1]="cat";
arr[2]="there";
arr[3]="apple";
arr[4]="flower";
```

The sorted output should be...

```
apple
cat 
flower
hello
there
```

Also I don't understand what I should do if I have 2 words like "Hello" and "Hell?" Everywhere the examples are always for integers and never strings especially in C++.

Comment: (1) Yes, it's possible to merge sort an array of strings, (2) make sure that your compare function handles the case `"Hello"`/`"Hell"` appropriately (usually that means that `"Hell" < "Hello"`).

Comment: So for Hall and Hell is Hall>Hell?

Comment: What? Certainly not. Maybe we disagree about the `<` sign. By `Hell < Hello` I mean that `Hell` would go before `Hello`. I certainly hope you're not asking whether `Hell` should be before `Hall` alphabetically....

Comment: Sorry, but I was wondering about 2 strings like Hall and Hell.!

Comment: [`std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)?

Comment: I have to implement the merge sort :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your comparision, use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) for C, and [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) for C++. Both functions will compare the strings, and return an integer with the following meanings...

- **< 0**    —   Either the value of the first character that does not match is lower in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is shorter.
- **= 0**   —   They compare equal
- **> 0**   —   Either the value of the first character that does not match is greater in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is longer.

This will also take into account "Hello" vs. "Hell" and will will subsequently sort "Hell" before "Hello".

*Note:* If you find that you are like me, and have a hard time remembering what the result means. Simply put the comparison operator (as in the example above) inbetween `str1` and `str2`. So, for example, if you called `strcmp(str1, str2)` and the result was **< 0**, then look at it like `str1 < str2`.